# What NSDate Format is this?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date that seems to be slightly different than any format I've seen:

```
2017-07-17T13:49:44.000+0000
```

It's the .000 right before the +0000 that throws me off. Anyone know what the NSDate Format is for this (ex: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ)? Thanks!

Comment: It's fractional seconds: `.SSS`.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` (fractional seconds). [Reference](https://www.nsdateformatter.com/).

Comment: The proper reference is from the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: @LeoDabus `Z` and `xxxx` are the same thing. Please see the [standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns). The discussion of `Z (1..3)` states it's the same as `xxxx`.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right. I just realized Z doesn't use Z for UTC